# How to do string operations (concatenation) in a python list?

Tags: python, list

probably this has been answered before, but I was searching for a while and have not found a solution.

How can I concatenate strings with strings in a python list?

MWE:

```
a = ["fcd", "f", "D"]

prefix = "la/"
postfix = ".d"

# desired a modified:
# a = prefix + a + postfix 
a = ["la/fcd.d", "la/f.d", "la/D.d"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour.  We expect you to look up basic techniques on your own before posting here.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Got a real stack overflow ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a = [prefix + item + postfix for item in a]
```